# Prove that $(1+\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{ab+bc+ca})^{\frac{(a+b+c)^2}{a^2+b^2+c^2}} \leq (1+\frac{a}{b})(1+\frac{b}{c})(1+\frac{c}{a})$

Tags: inequality, contest-math, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

> Assuming $a,b,c>0$, show that
> $$\Big(1+\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{ab+bc+ca}\Big)^{\frac{(a+b+c)^2}{a^2+b^2+c^2}} \leq \Big(1+\frac{a}{b}\Big)\Big(1+\frac{b}{c}\Big)\Big(1+\frac{c}{a}\Big).$$

I know from CS that $ab+bc+ca \leq a^2+b^2+c^2$ and $(a+b+c)^2 \leq 3(a^2+b^2+c^2)$ so the exponent is less than 3 and the second term in parenthesis greater than $1$, but I can't manage to convert this information, might work on the right hand side but seems like I'm missing a classical inequality since I'm a very beginner in this.
I noticed this inequality is symmetrical and homogeneous, maybe assuming $a+b+c=1$ could be useful...

Comment: Where does this inequality come from?

Comment: Maybe with Bernoulli's inequality

Comment: See problem 6 https://imomath.com/index.cgi?page=inequalitiesJensenAndKaramata

Comment: A friend told me about this one, it was one brought to him by one of his professors, also thanks for editing my post @RobertZ

Comment: I can't figure out where nor Bernouilli's inequality would help there, the exponent needs to be in [0,1] for the inequality to be in the right order but then I can't link it to the RHS, maybe with tricky CS usages... @Anamaria

Comment: I can't see where this result on problem 6 would help here again, the exponent is not an integer so seems it doesn't apply, but thanks @ErikSatie

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $x = \frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{ab + bc + ca}$. Then $x \ge 1$.

Using Bernoulli inequality, we have
$$\mathrm{LHS} = (1 + x)^{1 + 2/x} = (1 + x)\Big((1 + x)^{1/x}\Big)^2
\le (1 + x)\left(1 + x\cdot \frac{1}{x}\right)^2 = 4 + 4x.$$

It suffices to prove that
$$4 + \frac{4(a^2+b^2+c^2)}{ab + bc + ca} \le \frac{(a + b)(b + c)(c + a)}{abc}$$
or (clearing the denominators)
$$(b-c)^2a^3 + (b^3 + c^3)a^2 - 2bc(b^2 + c^2)a + b^2c^2(b + c) \ge 0.$$
It suffices to prove that
$$ (b^3 + c^3)a^2 - 2bc(b^2 + c^2)a + b^2c^2(b + c) \ge 0$$
which is true since
$$(b^3 + c^3)a^2 + b^2c^2(b + c) \ge 2\sqrt{(b^3 + c^3)a^2 \cdot b^2c^2(b + c)}
\ge 2abc(b^2 + c^2)$$
where we have used AM-GM and Cauchy-Bunyakovsky-Schwarz.

We are done.

Comment: Great solution ! Thanks

Comment: @brandon You are welcome.

Comment: Last equality should be inequality, no? Nice solution otherwise.

Comment: @V.S.e.H. Yes. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

I use $abc$'s method .

Let $a+b+c=3u,ab+bc+ca=3v^2,abc=w^3$ then the problem is :

$$\frac{3u3v^2}{w^3}-1\geq \left(1+\frac{9u^2-6v^2}{3v^2}\right)^{\frac{9u^2}{9u^2-6v^2}}$$

A bit of algebra and the inequality is linear in $w$ and as it's homogeneous we can assume $a=b=1$ so we need to show :

$$\Big(1+\frac{2+c^2}{1+2c}\Big)^{\frac{(2+c)^2}{2+c^2}} \leq 2\Big(1+\frac{1}{c}\Big)\Big(1+c\Big)$$

We use logarithm the inequality now is :

$$\frac{(2+c)^2}{2+c^2}\ln\Big(1+\frac{2+c^2}{1+2c}\Big)\leq \ln(2)+\ln(1+c)+\ln\Big(1+\frac{1}{c}\Big)$$

We introduce the function :

$$f\left(x\right)=\frac{(2+x)^{2}}{2+x^{2}}\ln\left(1+\frac{2+x^{2}}{1+2x}\right)-\left(\ln\left(2\right)+\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)+\ln\left(x+1\right)\right)$$

Now I haven't an idea to conclude except that we have for $x\in(0,10]$:

$$\ln\left(2\right)+\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)+\ln\left(x+1\right)\geq\left(\left(\ln\left(2\right)+\frac{\ln\left(2\right)}{x}+\ln\left(2\right)\ln\left(xe\right)\right)\left(\frac{x}{x+1}\right)+\frac{1}{x+1}\cdot3\ln\left(2\right)\right)\geq \frac{(2+x)^{2}}{2+x^{2}}\ln\left(1+\frac{2+x^{2}}{1+2x}\right)$$

Wich is easier I think .

Edit :

the inequality is :

$$\left(1+\frac{2\left(1+2x\right)}{2+x^{2}}\right)\ln\left(1+\frac{\left(2+x^{2}\right)}{1+2x}\right)\leq \ln\left(2\right)+\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)+\ln\left(x+1\right)$$

Setting $a=\frac{\left(1+2x\right)}{2+x^{2}},b=\frac{1}{x},c=1+x$ :

$$\left(1+2a\right)\ln\left(1+a^{-1}\right)\leq \ln\left(1+b\right)+\ln\left(2\right)+\ln\left(c\right)$$

With the constraint $$a=\frac{\left(c+b^{-1}\right)}{2+b^{-2}}$$

Wich is easier with derivatives .