# A possible lower bound for $\left(1+\frac{a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}}{ab+bc+ca}\right)^{\frac{\left(a+b+c\right)^{2}}{\left(a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}\right)}}$

Tags: inequality, examples-counterexamples

Problem :

Let $a,b,c>0$ then it seems we have :
$$\left(1+\frac{a}{b+c}\right)\left(1+\frac{b}{c+a}\right)\left(1+\frac{c}{a+b}\right)<\left(1+\frac{a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}}{ab+bc+ca}\right)^{\frac{\left(a+b+c\right)^{2}}{\left(a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}\right)}}
$$

Some related work :

You can fin an upper bound here [Prove that $(1+\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{ab+bc+ca})^{\frac{(a+b+c)^2}{a^2+b^2+c^2}} \leq (1+\frac{a}{b})(1+\frac{b}{c})(1+\frac{c}{a})$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4467314/prove-that-1-fraca2b2c2abbcca-fracabc2a2b2c2-le?noredirect=1#comment9362268_4467314) with a nice solution due to user RiverLi . Unfortunetaly <s>Bernoulli's inequality doesn't works here</s>  . I also tried to use Jensen's inequality with the logarithm but it doesn't works too . For an interesting fact let $a=b=1$ and $c\to \infty$ . To conclude on this remark we have some similarity with Nesbitt's inequality .

Edit :

Using Bernoulli's inequality we need to show :

$$1+\left(\frac{a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}}{ab+bc+ca}\right)\frac{\left(a+b+c\right)^{2}}{\left(a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}\right)}>\left(1+\frac{a}{b+c}\right)\left(1+\frac{b}{c+a}\right)\left(1+\frac{c}{a+b}\right)$$

Wich seems true .

Second Edit :

For $c=0$ we have the equality :

$$\left(1+\left(\frac{a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}}{ab+bc+ca}\right)\frac{\left(a+b+c\right)^{2}}{\left(a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}\right)}\right)-\left(\left(1+\frac{a}{b+c}\right)+\left(1+\frac{b}{c+a}\right)+\left(1+\frac{c}{a+b}\right)\right)=0$$

Wich show the inequality in this case

Question :

> > How to (dis)prove it ?

Comment: This probably has some obnoxious trick to turn it into AGM.

Comment: use Bernoulli with two terms.

Comment: @dezdichado Feel free to make an answer If you have someting good or a trick .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After applying Bernoulli's inequality, note that the $a^2+b^2+c^2$ terms cancel. So we're looking at
$$
1+\frac{(a+b+c)^2}{ab + bc+ ca}> \frac{(a+b+c)^3}{(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)}
$$
Multiply through by $(ab+bc+ca)$ and note that $(a+b+c)(ab+bc+ca) = (a+b)(b+c)(c+a)+abc$, giving
$$
ab+bc+ca + (a+b+c)^2 > (a+b+c)^2 + \frac{abc(a+b+c)^2}{(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)}
$$
Cancel terms and divide by $abc$ to get
$$
\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c} > \frac{(a+b+c)^2}{(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)}
$$
At this point we can note that
$$
\frac{1}{a} +\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c} > \frac{1}{a+b}+\frac{1}{b+c}+\frac{1}{a+c} = \frac{(a+b+c)^2 + ab + ac+bc}{(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)}
$$
so the inequality is satisfied whenever $a,b,c>0$.

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment :

It seems we have the inequalities for $a,b,c>0$

$$1+\left(\frac{a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}}{ab+bc+ca}\right)\frac{\left(a+b+c\right)^{2}}{\left(a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}\right)}-\left(1+\frac{a}{b+c}\right)\left(1+\frac{b}{c+a}\right)\left(1+\frac{c}{a+b}\right)\geq \left(1+\left(\frac{a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}}{ab+bc+ca}\right)\frac{\left(a+b+c\right)^{2}}{\left(a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}\right)}\right)-\left(\left(1+\frac{a}{b+c}\right)+\left(1+\frac{b}{c+a}\right)+\left(1+\frac{c}{a+b}\right)\right)+1$$

So if true we need to show :

$$\left(1+\left(\frac{a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}}{ab+bc+ca}\right)\frac{\left(a+b+c\right)^{2}}{\left(a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}\right)}\right)-\left(\left(1+\frac{a}{b+c}\right)+\left(1+\frac{b}{c+a}\right)+\left(1+\frac{c}{a+b}\right)\right)+1\geq 0$$

I haven't the time yet but I shall try $uvw's$ method .

Answer (score 0):

Let $\sigma\in S_3$ be a permutation of the symmetric group $S_3$. The by the symmetry of the function it is obvious that:

$$\hat{\sigma}[f](a,b,c) = f(\sigma(a),\sigma(b),\sigma(c)) = f(a,b,c)$$

This implies that if there is a minimum, it will be reached for $a = b = c = \lambda$, so in turn, we have:

$$\left(1+\frac{a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}}{ab+bc+ca}\right)^{\frac{\left(a+b+c\right)^{2}}{\left(a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}\right)}} = \left(1+\frac{3\lambda^{2}}{3\lambda^2}\right)^{\frac{\left(3\lambda\right)^{2}}{\left(3\lambda^2\right)}} = 2^3$$